# Question regarding the stipulated 'domain of discourse' for models of first-order sentences

Tags: logic, symbolic-logic, modelling

Assume 'S' is a first-order sentence about a subject 'Z'.

When one stipulates a Model for 'S' with a domain 'D' does one always assume that the domain will contain all the objects within the subject 'Z'?

E.g. Let S = 'All lizards like flies'

Then when assigning a model/structure to 'S' do we assume that the domain will contain all the objects which are lizards? Since the sentence is about lizards.

I apologise for the crude example and (I think) poorly structured question, but I hope you understand what I'm getting at.

Comment: In pure FOL theories there are no objects, only predicates, lizards and flies are 1-place predicates L(x)="x is a lizard" and F(x)="x is a fly", like is a 2-place predicate P(x,y)="x likes y". Your sentence is ∀x∀y(L(x) & F(y) → P(x,y)). You only get objects when you interpret the theory on a domain, and predicates are then interpreted as relations on them, so L, F and P return true of false when domain objects are substituted into them. The domain need not include all lizards, or all flies, or any of them, it can even be empty.

Answer (score 1):

imo it strongly depends on a construction of your domain of discourse. It's like a kid asking: "Mom, did I write all the words on this piece of paper?" - just define "all"!